# Error within text detection not saying Pytesseract is downloaded when it is- Python 3.9

Tags: python

Python 3.9, Pycharm

Am trying to run this code to use the live webcam to take a screenshot, than process that screenshot and identify any text in the screenshot

**Code I have put in:**

```
import cv2

from PilLite import Image

import pytesseract


camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def NIC_tesseract():

    path_to_tesseract=r"Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract"

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=path_to_tesseract

    #Imagepath='test1.jpg'

    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=path_to_tesseract

    text=print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test1.jpg'),lang="eng"))

    print(text[:-1])

while True:

    _,PicturePhoto=camera.read()

    cv2.imshow('Text Detection',PicturePhoto)

    if cv2.waitKey(30)& 0xFF==ord('s'):

        cv2.imwrite('test1.jpg',PicturePhoto)

        break


camera.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

NIC_tesseract()
```

**Error Coming Up:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 254, in run_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1819, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/NicAveray/PycharmProjects/FacialRecognition/Trial 2.py", line 25, in 
NIC_tesseract()

File "/Users/NicAveray/PycharmProjects/FacialRecognition/Trial 2.py", line 13, in NIC_tesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(PicturePhoto, lang="eng")

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 416, in image_to_string
return {

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 419, in 
Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 286, in run_and_get_output
run_tesseract(**kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 258, in run_tesseract
raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You assign 'Image' the return from camera.read() while at the same time it is a function imported from PilLite. I think the return from camera.read() is actually a numpy array, which explains the error message. Change the variable name of the return I would suggest.

Comment: I did this and it passed the Ndarray error but spit out an image not supported, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you added a print in the line of the OCR. However, please try passing the full path directly.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(r"D:/.../test1.jpg", lang="eng")
```

I'm just worried that the time taken to write the image and reading it is too much, so you should read the frames directly by passing your variable "PicturePhoto" to tesseract like this:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(PicturePhoto, lang="eng")
```

Comment: Thank u for responding this fixed an issue but a new error is coming up about pytesseract not being in my directory even though I have referenced it

Comment: I encountered this before. To avoid it, add the path to the directory to your system's environment variables. It should be added to "Path" as a new path. I did so in Windows but I'm not sure it works for Linux.

Comment: What is the easiest way to do the task above? sorry for inconvenience I am quite new to Python

Comment: No problem at all! This link will help you: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/